# python tkinter AttributeError: 'X' object has no attribute 'Y'

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm writing a Tkinter GUI, the code would ask the user to select a file (txt, pdf, or xlsx). Done with the selection, the user will click 'open' button and the code should fill in the entry widget with the path of that file. E.g. `D:/python/test.txt`

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from tkinter import END

root = tk.Tk()

class GUI:

    def __int__(self):

        self.filepath = ""
        self.filepath_labelframe = tk.LabelFrame()
        self.filepath_label = tk.Label()
        self.filepath_entry = tk.Entry()
        self.filepath_button = tk.Button()

    def openfilepath(self):

        self.filepath = fd.askopenfilename(title="Select A File",
                                           initialdir="/",
                                           filetypes=(("txt files", "*.txt"),
                                                      ("xlsx files", "*.xlsx"),
                                                      ("pdf files", "*.pdf"),
                                                      ("all files", "*.*")))

        self.filepath_entry.delete(0, END)
        self.filepath_entry.insert(0, self.filepath)

        return self.filepath

    def pathgui(self):

        self.filepath_labelframe = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="PATH")
        self.filepath_labelframe.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=25)

        self.filepath_label = tk.Label(self.filepath_labelframe, text="File Path: ")
        self.filepath_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=10)

        self.filepath_entry = tk.Entry(self.filepath_labelframe)
        self.filepath_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=10, ipadx=80)

        self.filepath_button = tk.Button(self.filepath_labelframe, text="Browse",
                                         command=lambda: GUI().openfilepath())
        self.filepath_button.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=10)

pathgui = GUI().pathgui()

root.mainloop()
```

The error code is this part:

```
        self.filepath_entry.delete(0, END)
        self.filepath_entry.insert(0, self.filepath)
```

The error message is:

> File "D:\PycharmProjects\GUI.py", line 29, in openfilepath
> self.filepath_entry.delete(0, END)
> AttributeError: 'GUI' object has no attribute 'filepath_entry'

Could someone explain how can I solve this error?

Comment: `def __int__(self)` You misspelled `__init__`.

Comment: @JohnGordon sry I didn't check the spelling, cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the user will click 'open' button and the code should fill in the
> entry widget with the path of that file. E.g. D:/python/test.txt

The problem can be fixed.

```
Add self parameter in `lambda: GUI.openfilepath(self))`
```

Code:

```
self.filepath_button = tk.Button(self.filepath_labelframe, text="Browse",
                                 command=lambda: GUI.openfilepath(self))
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering why the path wouldn't show up. Your comment really help :)